# firefox font-face issue

Tags: firefox, font-face

So have a very strange issue in firefox with font-face. I've included all the different font version types (.ttf, .woff, etc.) but don't see it loading in the browser (works fine in chrome). However, when I inspect it with firebug and hover over the font name in the inspector, *it previews it correctly*. So it is loading the font somewhat, but not in the main browser window. Anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 1):

It ended up being that if font-family has spaces in it you need to surround it with double quotes not single :P

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess: do you use NoScript?  It blocks downloaded fonts by default.  (Rationale is that font engines weren't necessarily designed for arbitrary input and may be just as vulnerable to attack as anything else.)